# Removing object from array and replacing it with object from another array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, for-loop

The problem I have encountered is as follows: I have created two array  representing docking spaces for ships. The first array ship object be saved in the array and if there is no space then it will be added to a waiting list array. **But when I remove an object from the first array the object from the waiting list array is not removed and added.**

The dock can accommodate three sizes of ship; cargo, container and super-container. The rows are made up of 5 small and 3 medium and 2 large. A cargo ship (small) can berth in any available space. A container ship (medium) can berth in the medium space and large, but not in small spaces. A super-container can only fit in large space.

So if I enter shipName3 and Super-Container for example and there is already two Super-Container's it adds to the waiting list but when I remove a Super-Container from the dock it does not remove a ship from the waiting list and add it to the dock  Can you help? Here's my dock method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];
private static Ship[] waitingList = new Ship[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
}

public static void menu() {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
        System.out.println("1. Dock");
        System.out.println("2. Undock");
        System.out.println("3. Status");

        int menu = scan.nextInt();
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1. Dock");
                dock();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2. Undock");
                undock();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3. Status");
                printDock();
                printWaitingList();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("4. Exit");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("No such option");
                break;
        }
    }
}


public static void dock() {

    System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
    String size = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the ships dock:");
    //Check if the dock number is valid
    int i = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
    if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && dock1[i] == null) {
        int c = 0;
        int co = 0;
        int sco = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dock1.length; j++) {
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Cargo")) {
                c++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Container")) {
                co++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Super-Container")) {
                sco++;
            }
        }

        if (c < 10 && co < 5 && sco < 2) {
            //Add ship to the dock
            dock1[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space you can dock");
            System.out.println("Ship has been docked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot dock");
            waitingList(name,size);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't dock");
        waitingList(name, size);
    }

}


public static void undock() { 
    System.out.println("Status of ships: ");
    printDock();
    System.out.println("Enter ship's name to undock: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter ship's size to undock: ");
    String size = scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] != null && dock1[i].getShipName().equals(name)) {
            dock1[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Ship removed");
           //break;
            ///HERE CHECK IF SHIP IN DOCK
            for (int j = 0; j < dock1.length; j++) {
                if (dock1[j] == null) {
                    //Add ship to the dock
                    dock1[j] = new Ship(name, size);
                    System.out.println("Move ship from waiting list to dock 1");
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No space in dock1");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ship not docked here");
            break;
        }

    }

}

public static void waitingList(String name, String size){
    System.out.println("Dock 1 is full, ship will try to be added to Waiting List");
    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) { //waitingList?
        if (waitingList[i] == null) {
            //Add ship to the dock
            waitingList[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space added to waiting list");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No space on waiting list, ship turned away");
            return;
        }
    }

}

public static void printDock() {

    System.out.println("Docks:");

    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + dock1[i].getShipName() + " " + dock1[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}

private static void printWaitingList() {

    System.out.println("Waiting List:");

    for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
        if (waitingList[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + waitingList[i].getShipName() + " " + waitingList[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ship class

```
public class Ship {

private String shipName;
private  String shipSize;

public String getShipName() {
    return shipName;
}

public void setShipName(String shipName) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
}

public String getShipSize() {
    return shipSize;
}

public void setShipSize(String shipSize) {
    this.shipSize = shipSize;
}

public Ship(String shipName, String shipSize) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
    this.shipSize = shipSize;
}
}
```

I put my attempt in the undock method.

Comment: where is the error method name ?

Comment: The problem is in the undock class but there is no error message it just does not move the object

Comment: @S.smith94 when you will remove object from an array then you have to add elements from waiting list to array if objects are present in waiting list and if there is space in array? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @S.smith94 at the same time you have to remove object from waiting list

Comment: yes I need to remove it from the waiting list array and add to dock1 array

Comment: ///HERE CHECK IF SHIP IN DOCK
            for (int j = 0; j < dock1.length; j++) { dock1 is also in inner loop should it be waitingList

Comment: I have tested both waitingList and dock1 for that bit but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @S.smith94 have you tried my answer?

Comment: Just trying it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your **undock** method in that you are removing from **dock1** array and again you are adding to same object to **dock1** array but there is no code to remove object from **waitingList** array simply update your loop in undock method as mentioned below

```
for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] != null && dock1[i].getShipName().equals(name)) {
            dock1[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Ship removed");
            // break;
            /// HERE CHECK IF SHIP IN DOCK
            for (int j = 0; j < waitingList.length; j++) {
                if (dock1[i] == null) {
                    // Add ship to the dock
                    dock1[i] = new Ship(waitingList[j].getShipName(), waitingList[j].getShipSize());
                    System.out.println("Move ship from waiting list to dock 1");
                    waitingList[j]=null;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No space in dock1");
                    return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ship not docked here");
            break;
        }

    }
```

I have changed inner loop iteration so it will loop to the size of **waitingList** array because we need to remove object from **waitingList** aray and add to **dock1** array.Also i am runtime getting the **shipname** and **shipsize** from **waitingList** array so that it will add object from **waitingList** to **dock1** array. I have tested code to my machine working here hope it will help you.

Comment: @S.smith94 check elements in array

Answer (score 0):

In your undock method, you remove the ship at the i'th position in dock1 array by setting it to `null`. This is ok but then you have a for loop that runs through all of the ships in dock1 looking for one with a `null` valued one. You aready know the one you just removed is `null` because you just set it to that value. Then you set it equal to a new ship that has the exact name and size of the one you removed (essentially putting the ship back). Instead, you want the for loop to traverse your list of waiting ships to find one that matches the space of the ship you just removed.

Replace:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dock1.length; j++) {
    if (dock1[j] == null) {
        //Add ship to the dock
        dock1[j] = new Ship(name, size);
        System.out.println("Move ship from waiting list to dock 1");
        break;
     } else {
         System.out.println("No space in dock1");
         return;
     }
 }
```

with

```
for (int j = 0; j < waitingList.length; j++) {
    if (waitingList[j].getShipSize() <= size) {
        //Add ship to the dock
        dock1[i] = waitingList[j];
        System.out.println("Move ship from waiting list to dock 1");
        return;
    }
}
System.out.println("No space in dock1");
return;
```